# Failed attempt to expect and send in an expect script in MinGW

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, shell, mingw

I’m using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) and I am trying to write an expect script which will run git clone.

My script:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git
expect "Enter passphrase for key..."
send "myPassword"
read -p "enter..."
```

And after run it I got:

```
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Enter passphrase for key...: |
```

And the program is waiting for password now, it seems like `expect` and `send` don’t work properly.

Here is a very basic test I have made:

```
echo "hello"
expect "hello"
read -p "enter..."
send "\r"
```

And here is what I got:

```
hello
bash: expect: command not found
enter...
```

What can be wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don’t have [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) installed on your system.

If the error is this:

```
bash: expect: command not found
```

To confirm, try using `which` like this:

```
which expect
```

If you have that installed on your system, it will return the full file path to `expect`. If it returns nothing? Then `expect` is not installed.

I am not 100% familiar with [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org), but in general `expect` is a command line tool that is not installed by default on pretty much all systems. It needs to be installed manually — via package installer or source code — on whatever system that needs to use it.

Below is the contents of the answer I posted when I thought the issue was with syntax and logic in `expect` itself.

---

Your `expect` script is this:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git
expect "Enter passphrase for key..."
send "myPassword"
read -p "enter..."
```

You might need to hit <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> at the end of that `send` like this:

```
send "myPassword\r"
```

Or you can try formatting the `expect` and `send` so the `send` is an explicit conditional of the other like this:

```
expect "Enter passphrase for key..." { send "myPassword\r" }
```

And — almost missed this — but your main command needs to be run with `spawn` like this:

```
spawn "git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git"
```

So with those two changes, your final script would be something like this:

```
spawn "git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git"
expect "Enter passphrase for key..." { send "myPassword\r" }
read -p "enter..."
```

But not 100% sure what that `read -p "enter..."` is for; doesn’t seem useful or in context with the rest of the script. So remove it and try doing simply this:

```
spawn "git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git"
expect "Enter passphrase for key..." { send "myPassword\r" }
```

All that said, you should setup SSH keys with Git. Entering a password all the time is really a tedious and miserable way to use Git and it seems like this script is attempting to make that easier? I highly recommend getting SSH keys established so you don’t have to do this or even store your password in a shell script.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line of the expect script start with `spawn`?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Won't these examples wait for stdin or something like that rather than capture process output? It's been a while since I used `expect`, but this feels odd. Also all examples that actually start a process use the `spawn` keyword in these examples.