# How to get output from the console and act on it without expect?

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, git, mingw

I have read in [another question’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1610071/167207) that if you want to use expect like this:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git
expect "Enter passphrase for key..."
send "myPassword\r"
read -p "enter..."
```

You have to install `expect` to use this *but* I can’t install anything external on this system. I am using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org).

My question is: Is it possible to get output from console — and act on it — using something different than expect?

Comment: This is a good follow up to [the other question](https://superuser.com/q/1610065/167207). Adding context by linking and clarifying you are on MinGW so others can better understand what your situation is. Best of luck with this!

Comment: You say you can't install anything extra.. can you put the `expect` binary on an external drive and add it to your path before running these commands?

Comment: unfortunately I can't, I'm very limited :(